# if condition inside html

Tags: python, html, css, if-statement

I am new in `django`. Here I'm try to do a poll app using `django` .
I want to display '**you entered correct**'

```
if selected_choice='Yellow'
```

Here is my code

```
def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
    else:

        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        context_dict={}
        context_dict['selected_choice']=selected_choice
        context_dict['question']=question

        return render(request, 'polls/result.html', context_dict)
```

html file

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if selected_choice  %}
    {% if 'Yellow' %}

    <p> you entered correct </p>
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}


<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{     choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: the following if condition in html file did not work properly.

Comment: This if condition inside html is better called templates :)

Comment: Why did you split your `if` statement into two statements? Does `{% if selected_choice == 'Yellow' %}` solve the problem?

Comment: @rkatkam has the correct answer below - see the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If selected_choice is a string value:

The white-space before and after '==' is important; which is usually missed.

```
   {% if selected_choice == 'Yellow' %}
    <p> you entered correct </p>
   {% endif %}
```

You may also try:

```
   {% ifequal selected_choice 'Yellow' %} 
    <p> you entered correct </p>
   {% endifequal %}
```

Comment: what is 'selected_choice'? Is it an object? I assume so because you calling save() method on it. Are you storing the value say 'Yellow' as one of its field? In such case you need to state that like {% if selected_choice.name == "Yellow" %}.

Comment: i got it..i convert the type(selected_choice) to string.that produce exact answer